# Map<String, User> in yaml file for @ConfirgurationProperties in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-boot-configuration

Hello I have a configuration class in a spring boot project that looks something like this .

```
  @ConfigurationProperties(config.value) 
     public class ApplicationProperties{
              Map<String, User> userProperties;
        }
       
     public class User{
              String userName;
              String userCity;
      }
```

How do I give value for userProperties in my application.yaml file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your example, the corresponding configuration properties for two different users in `application.yml` would look as follows:

```
userProperties:
  user1:
    userName: jane
    userCity: New York
  user2:
    userName: john
    userCity: Lisbon
```